# How to find last index in Pandas Data Frame row and count backwards using column information?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

For example:

If I have a data frame like this:

```
      20  40  60  80  100  120  140
 1    1   1   1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 2    1   1   1   1    1   NaN  NaN
 3    1   1   1   1   NaN  NaN  NaN
 4    1   1  NaN NaN   1    1    1
```

How do I find the last index in each row and then count the difference in columns elapsed so I get something like this?

```
      20  40  60  80  100  120  140
 1    40  20   0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 2    80  60  40  20    0   NaN  NaN
 3    60  40  20  0    NaN  NaN  NaN
 4    20  0   NaN NaN   40  20   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try of Transposing the dataframe, then after count only not null values and last set 1

```
#bit of complex procedure, solution involving with.
def fill_values(df):
    df = df[::-1]
    a = df == 1
    b = a.cumsum()
    #Function in counting the cummulative not null values
    arr = np.where(a, b-b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int), 1)
    return (b-b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int))[::-1]*20
df.apply(fill_values,1).replace(0,np.nan)-20
```

Out:

```
    20      40      60    80    100     120 140
1   40.0    20.0    0.0   NaN   NaN     NaN NaN
2   80.0    60.0    40.0  20.0  0.0     NaN NaN
3   60.0    40.0    20.0  0.0   NaN     NaN NaN
4   20.0    0.0     NaN   NaN   40.0    20.0    0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!